# How do link a file user uploaded via pre-signed url to Database?

Tags: python, django

This is how I was saving user uploaded Files:

```
f = request.FILES[x]
s = File(file=f, user=curUser)
s.save()
```

This worked great but it took a lot of bandwidth on my server so I decided to use pre-signed urls.

Now users upload directly to s3 Bucket, however it's not linked to Database.

I tried this which runs after user successfully uploads to S3:

```
f = default_storage.open(userID + "/" + fileName)
curUser = User.objects.get(userID=userID)
s = File(file=f, user=curUser)
s.save()
f.close()
```

However, this is just creating a new folder on users directory and uploading it there.

my Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=101,primary_key=True)

class File(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(max_length=255, upload_to=user_directory_path)

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    path = instance.user.userID + "/" + filename
    return path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common method is to configure the `s3 bucket` to invoke a `lambda function`
on the file upload event.

Then inside your lambda you update the databse with the uploaded object.

Here is an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Answer (score 1):

- after doing this if your have done `makemigrations` and then `migrate` then table named `File` will be created in your database.
- which will have two field **user** and **file** where **file** will contains the path of images uploaded.
- now you can access the database like `File.objects.all()` to get all the rows from ***File*** table.

Comment: I already have the database up and running. problem is I switched from uploads being done on server to client side. Now i need to associate the uploaded files in my s3 bucket to file model.

Comment: then you will have all images path stored in your database table. and you can access that and use in your app.